# connect ECONNREFUSED in Postman when i try to send a POST request

Tags: postman

Im trying to build an api with postman. When i want to send a post request it gives me this error:

POST https://localhost:44360/api/Aufgabe
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:44360
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.36.3
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 9391e8b8-0f88-4f74-89f0-02a627f72ef6
Host: localhost:44360
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

I wanted to ask if anyone could help me to solve this.

This is the LaunchSettings code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:35266",
      "sslPort": 44360
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "library",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5224",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "library",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7267;http://localhost:5224",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I checked my firewalls settings and also the settings in my Postman but nothing helped. I again checked my code and the ports and everything should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

The error `ECONNREFUSED` means that a connection could not be established to the destination you provided in the URL.

We can see by your code you're trying to connect to IP `127.0.0.1` at port `44360`.

This IP is a loopback address, meaning it points back to the computer where you run Postman. Most likely the problem is that you don't have a service running on your computer which listens on the given port.

It is unlikely that this is due to a firewall issue unless you have an obscure configuration that blocks the computer's access to itself.

- Verify that IIS is indeed listening on port `44360` when using SSL
- Try to access using HTTP instead of HTTPS and see if that works